# Error: "Invalid teamId and/or appId specified" for Task module submit action in Tabs

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm having a input form in Task module in Microsoft Teams Tabs, but while submitting the task module from Tabs in giving me error as "Invalid teamId and/or appId specified", i have cross checked the App id is correct.
What could be the issue.

`microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(objectInfo, "MicrosoftAppId");`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below format.

> microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(customerInfo, "#{appId}");

Here is the [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs/blob/master/src/views/customform.pug) file.

Answer (score 0):

So in your example, it's not supposed to the actual string "MicrosoftAppId", it's supposed to be the actual AppId for your bot - make sure that's the case. However, it doesn't *actually* need the AppId to work, you can try without it, like so:

```
microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(objectInfo);
```

It depends, I think, on what you're trying to do whether you need the AppId to be specified, but it's definitely not needed for all cases. For your example, where you're launching the Task Module from a tab itself, you probably don't need it as you can do whatever you need with "objectInfo" on the calling tab.